# Sails.js: How to actually run tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, sails.js, mocha.js

I'm completely new to sails, node and js in general so I might be missing something obvious.

I'm using sails 0.10.5 and node 0.10.33.

In the sails.js documentation there's a page about tests http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Testing, but it doesn't tell me how to actually run them.

I've set up the directories according to that documentation, added a test called test/unit/controllers/RoomController.test.js and now I'd like it to run.

There's no 'sails test' command or anything similar. I also didn't find any signs on how to add a task so tests are always run before a 'sails lift'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See my test structure in we.js: https://github.com/wejs/we-example/tree/master/test

You can copy and paste in you sails.js app and remove we.js plugin feature in bootstrap.js

And change you package.json to use set correct mocha command in npm test: https://github.com/wejs/we-example/blob/master/package.json#L10

-- edit --

I created a simple sails.js 0.10.x test example, see in: https://github.com/albertosouza/sails-test-example

Comment: Thank you very much. I can now use `npm test` to run the tests.

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE-2:** After struggling a lil bit with how much it takes to run unit test this way, i decided to create a module to load the models and turn them into globals just as sails does, but without taking so much. Even when you strip out every hook, but the orm-loader depending on the machine, it can easily take a couple seconds WITHOUT ANY TESTS!, and as you add models it gets slower, so i created this module called [**waterline-loader**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/waterline-loader) so you can load just the basics (Its about 10x faster), the module is not stable and needs test, but you are welcome to use it or modify it to suit your needs, or help me out to improve it here -> https://github.com/Zaggen/waterline-loader

---

**UPDATE-1:** 
I've added the info related to running your tests with mocha to the [docs](http://sailsjs.org/#/!/documentation/concepts/Testing) under **Running tests** section.

---

Just to expand on what others have said (specially what Alberto Souza said).

You need two steps in order to make mocha work with sails as you want. First, as stated in the [sails.js Docs](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/Testing) you need to lift the server before running your test, and to do that, you create a file called bootstrap.test.js (It can be called anything you like) in the root path (optional) of your tests (test/bootstrap.test.js) that will be called first by mocha, and then it'll call your test files.

```
var Sails = require('sails'),
  sails;

before(function(done) {
  Sails.lift({
    // configuration for testing purposes
  }, function(err, server) {
    sails = server;
    if (err) return done(err);
    // here you can load fixtures, etc.
    done(err, sails);
  });
});

after(function(done) {
  // here you can clear fixtures, etc.
  sails.lower(done);
});
```

Now in your package.json, on the scripts key, add this line(Ignore the comments)

```
 // package.json ....
 scripts": {
    // Some config 
    "test": "mocha test/bootstrap.test.js test/**/*.test.js"
  },
 // More config
```

This will load the bootstrap.test.js file, lift your sails server, and then runs all your test that use the format 'testname.test.js', you can change it to '.spec.js' if you prefer.

Now you can use `npm test` to run your test.

**Note** that you could do the same thing without modifying your package.json, and typying `mocha test/bootstrap.test.js test/**/*.test.js` in your command line

**PST:** For a more detailed configuration of the bootstrap.test.js check Alberto Souza answer or directly check this **[file](https://github.com/albertosouza/sails-test-example/blob/master/test/bootstrap.js)** in hist github repo

Answer (score 1):

Given that they don't give special instructions and that they use Mocha, I'd expect that running `mocha` from the command line while you are in the **parent** directory of `test` would work.

Answer (score 1):

Sails uses mocha as a default testing framework. 
But Sails do not handle test execution by itself.

So you have to run it manually using `mocha` command.

But there is an article how to make all Sails stuff included into tests. 
http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Testing